# only_full_group_by : "ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause"

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1055

Issue of mysql new version with only_full_group_by

I need to get table value using Group by (col_id) and order by (date)
and my code in mysql as following :

```
SELECT COUNT(created_date) AS `Rows` , ANY_VALUE(id) 
FROM `table` where `my_id` = 1 AND `status` = '0' 
GROUP BY `id` 
ORDER BY `created_date` DESC
```

I'm Getting error as follow

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'database.table.created_date' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Any one say the solution ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: disable the only_full_group_by `mysql> set global sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
mysql> set session sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error related to only\_full\_group\_by when executing a query in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql)

Comment: The whole point of the `GROUP BY` errors are that they signal logic errors. It is not possible to `ORDER BY created_date` because there is no such expression in the `SELECT` clause and each group probably contains two or more different values for `created_date`. Which one to use for sorting? Disabling the `sql_mode` doesn't solve the problem, it just makes MySQL return indeterminate results.

Answer (score 0):

With "only full group by", the `order by` cannot be an arbitrary column.  The `order by` is parsed *after* the `group by`, so only aggregaton keys and aggregated columns are allowed.

You could use:

```
SELECT COUNT(created_date) AS `Rows`, ANY_VALUE(id)
FROM `table` 
WHERE `my_id` = 1 AND `status` = '0'
GROUP BY `id`
ORDER BY ANY_VALUE(`created_date`) DESC;
```

If I had to guess, you actually want `MAX()`:

```
ORDER BY MAX(`created_date`) DESC;
```